# The necessary English skills to get a work-permit UK visa, for a postdoc position

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visa, ielts, toefl

I am a quality-oriented recent graduate PhD in Chemical Engineering at from University of Tehran, Iran. 
During my PhD I passed two sabbatical periods at University of Waterloo in Canada for 8 months and at California Institute of Technology for 16 months.

I am wondering if it is necessary to have an updated IELTS or TOEFL score to get a work-permit UK visa for a postdoc job?

Thanks a lot for your time and attention,
Best Regards,
Nahid P. Khiabani

Comment: Please refer to the [official documentation](https://www.gov.uk/tier-2-general/knowledge-of-english) on Tier 2 General visas.

Comment: The admissions dept will tell you.

Comment: @SolarMike Admissions deal with students; postdocs are staff. Staff inquires go to HR, who are often less than useless when it comes to visa requests.

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov HR is useless for many things...

Comment: @Solar Mike HR is absolutely useless if the OP doesn't ask. <g>

Comment: What do you mean by an 'updated IELTS or TOEFL'. As far as I know they do no expire.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, having worked in an English speaking country doesn't count towards the Tier 2 visa language requirement. If you don't have a degree from an institution in an English speaking country, you're going to have to produce favourable results from an approved language test.